# Find the records which have several value in the other columns

Tags: sql

How do I find the `contract_id` which has both Type A and Type B?

```
record  contract_id        type
1          1                A
2          1                B
3          2                A
4          2                A
5          3                B
6          3                B
```

At here, I hope we can find the `contract_id` 1, because it have both type A and type B.

Thank you so much.

Comment: In this example, yes.  Only A and B.  But I think there is an easy way to indicate which type we want. like A and B and C. Right?

Comment: At least Type A and Type B (and possibly some others) or only Type A and Type B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT contract_id
FROM YourTable
WHERE type IN ('A','B')
GROUP BY contract_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` on subqueries selecting the `A` and `B` records:

```
SELECT a.contract_id
FROM
    (SELECT record, contract_id 
    FROM Contract_type
    WHERE [type] = 'A') as a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT record, contract_id
    FROM Contract_type
    WHERE [type] = 'B') as b
ON a.contract_id = b.contract_id
```